# show multiple area into google map from database

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to show lat lon of some areas of a city into google map in javascript.I have a proper list of data  [data with area, lat, lon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmQv.png)
My javascript code is given below

```
<!--  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script> 
-->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=InitMap">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const uid = urlParams.get('uname')

let list=[];
var run;

var put =[];
collectArea();

function collectArea() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : "json",
        data: {userid : uid},
        url : 'UserlocationServlet?method=collectArea',
        success : function(data, status, xhr) {
            $.each(data, function(i,obj) {
                list.push([data[i].area,data[i].lat_no,data[i].lon_no]);
            });
            run=list;
            InitMap(run);

        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        }
    });
}   

function InitMap(locations) {
    alert(locations);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.8103,90.4125),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
</script>
```

But data in list is not showing in map.But I followed a documentation that includes

```
   var locations = [
        ['Raj Ghat', 28.648608, 77.250925, 1],
        ['Purana Qila', 28.618174, 77.242686, 2],
        ['Red Fort', 28.663973, 77.241656, 3],
        ['India Gate', 28.620585, 77.228609, 4],
        ['Jantar Mantar', 28.636219, 77.213846, 5],
        ['Akshardham', 28.622658, 77.277704, 6]
    ];
```

And these areas show in map.Please help me with this.

Comment: When you do `alert(locations);` do you see the array you expect?

Comment: yes i have given the screen shot of expected data

Comment: possibly try `position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(locations[i][1]), parseFloat(locations[i][2])),`

Comment: Do the locations show when you zoom out?  Do you get any JavaScript errors? Are the coordinates numbers or strings? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, including sample data.

Comment: Why are you manipulating the JSON data before passing to the `initMap` function? Creating the array rather than working with JSON seems ... unusual?!

Answer (score 1):

It is common to declare the `initMap` function as a callback in the script uri but in your case this is not necessarily the way to do it as you explicitly call the `InitMap` function in the AJAX callback and hope to pass some data to the `InitMap` function. Because of that you should assign the `collectArea` as the callback within the script uri.

I would suggest also that you do not need to manipulate the JSON data prior to passing to the `InitMap` function - it is, IMO, preferable to process the raw json data rather than worry about array indices so in the below I modified the flow so that the JSON remains unmodified before being consumed in the `initMap` function.

```
<!--
/*
    
    As you are calling the `InitMap` within the `collectArea` callback 
    function you should set the map script callback to `collectArea`!!
    
*/
-->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB5bEQj6ZsKK1pSOdWGhzL43s2R6pDr2-o&callback=collectArea"></script>
<script>

    function collectArea() {
        const qs = window.location.search;
        const p = new URLSearchParams(qs);
        const uid = p.get('uname');
        /*
            leave the source data as JSON and pass
            that to the `InitMap` function.
        */
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { userid : uid },
            url: 'UserlocationServlet?method=collectArea',
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                InitMap(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
    }   

    function InitMap( locations ) {
        /*
            After loading the map you can iterate through
            the JSON data and add a new marker for each 
            location.
        */
        const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng( 23.8103, 90.4125 ),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        
        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        
        const clickhandler=function(){
            /*
                This callback is `bound` to the marker so we
                can use `this` to refer to the marker itself.
                As the `area` data has been assigned as a custom
                property of the marker we can access it using 
                `this.area`
            */      
            infowindow.setContent( this.content );
            infowindow.open( map, this );       
        };

        
        // iterate over json data locations
        Object.keys( locations ).forEach( k=>{
            let obj=locations[k];
            
            let marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng( obj.lat_no, obj.lon_no ),
                map: map,
                content:obj.area    //custom property
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', clickhandler.bind( marker ) );  //bound marker
        })
    }
</script>
```